# Doing Math on Json values, doesn't work in For loop

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to replace values inside a JSON formatted variable.

This is my data format:

```
{
      "y":-10.9569,
      "x":26.4007,
      "z":11.9888,
      "t":109.122
    },
    {
      "y":-9.78734,
      "x":6.85818,
      "z":11.9832,
      "t":109.439
    },
    {
      "y":-9.30135,
      "x":-2.72265,
      "z":11.9493,
      "t":109.594
    },
    {
      "y":-7.90726,
      "x":-33.3971,
      "z":12.012,
      "t":110.14
    },
    {
      "y":-6.8483,
      "x":-56.5212,
      "z":11.916,
      "t":110.611
    },
```

I tried this code, but it outputs the values unchanged:

```
for(var i = 1; i < json.length; i++ ) {
            json.recording.path[i].t = json.recording.path[i].t*0.9;
    }
console.log(json);
```

But when I omit the `for` loop the code replaces the value correctly:

```
json.recording.path[1].t = json.recording.path[1].t*0.9;
console.log(json);
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Note that JSON is a text format. By the time it gets to your code, it's just an array of objects. It may help with your searching for your answers to ignore that the data you receive ever came from JSON.

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Comment: I believe the second expression of the loop should be `i < json.recording.path.length` and not `i < json.length`. Also `i` should start on `0` if you want to change the first element of the array too

Comment: Please show a more detailed example of the data you're working with. There is no `recording` or `path` in the data you've presented. Makes it harder to know what the problem is.

Comment: Put a log inside the loop to understand if and how many times its getting executed.

Comment: Yes, json.recording.path.length is needed, thanks for the help. I am starting on 1 on purpose because path[0].t is always 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the provided json data is not complete, from what you provided it should be

for(var i = 1; i < json.recording.path.length; i++ ) {
    ...

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating up to the length of the variable "json", but modifying 'json.recording.path".  You're also starting at index 1 instead of 0, which will cause it to skip the first element.

Try this instead:

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.recording.path.length; i++ ) {
```

(As several have pointed out in comments, this isn't JSON, it's a javascript object.  JSON is a string format for transporting and storing objects.)

Answer (score 0):

Using for loop you can iterate through the json elements and do the calculations.

```
var json = [{
      "y":-10.9569,
      "x":26.4007,
      "z":11.9888,
      "t":109.122
    },
    {
      "y":-9.78734,
      "x":6.85818,
      "z":11.9832,
      "t":109.439
    },
    {
      "y":-9.30135,
      "x":-2.72265,
      "z":11.9493,
      "t":109.594
    },
    {
      "y":-7.90726,
      "x":-33.3971,
      "z":12.012,
      "t":110.14
    },
    {
      "y":-6.8483,
      "x":-56.5212,
      "z":11.916,
      "t":110.611
    }];

    for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
       json[i].t = json[i].t * 0.9;
       console.log(json[i].t);
    }
```